# Couchbase community, mapping path /data in other structure

Tags: memcached, couchbase

today I'm having an issue about couchbase again, I'm having a problem with rebalance.

First, for performance purpose and solve IO issues on our servers, we mapped the /data with ramdisk service, this is a good thing on the one hand, as said improved performance d + for those who have to work with some memcached bucket, to the other buckets in my structure do not use the technique.

A little more use of memcached:

-->Today we have 4 buckets: bucket 1,2 and 3 - type couchbase and bucket 4 - type memcached

How to practice the /data path in our organization we map "/data/couchbase", so when start of couchbase we have the buckets mounted:
-/data/couchbase/bucket1
-/data/couchbase/bucket2
-/data/couchbase/bucket3
-/data/couchbase/bucket4

As previously reported, bucket4 is of memcached type and for IO reduction we use a ramdisk service mapping the entire path "/data/couchbase/bucket4" so that just after couchbase start this path is 100% in memory - Believe me, works great, the performance is great!

But as every good thing there are problems, the fact is that when the couchbase start it removes the directory "/bucket4" given the characteristic of memcached - this fact prevents for example of letting "autofailover" enabled, because if the cluster in question requires rebalance it will try to remove the "/ bucket4" diaries from memcached to insert any new members into the cluster.

To solve this for now, we are working on a script to detect any anomaly in a cluster member, as we will either add or remove, followed by rebalance a new member by stopping and uploading the ramdisk service.

With all this history, I want to show two things:

- 1 The technique of using a ramdisck service to treat memcached buckets is good for stable cluster cases
- 2 anyway ask everyone if they know any way to map a specific bucket to a different path to /data/bucket? so I could put my memcached buckets at another directory level so it could be removed, even if it was in a ramdisck structure.

Comment: memcached buckets does not write data to disk, everything is store in memory. A data folder is not created for memcached bucket on disk. It's strongly recommended that a ramdisk is not used with Couchbase Server. If you can explain what the performance issue were we can investigate them further.

Comment: Hello, you're correct! all memcached bucket is written in memory I'm agree! this is not the problem that I want to present, but about ramdisk we have to talk more about.
**Separating in two points:** 1 -> I want to know if there is any way to create a different path for each bucket, for example bucket A are memcached, bucket B are couchbase;
2 -> ramdisk I used to performance in my cluster when I put my memcached bucket mounted on it;
I want to explore point 1, on point 2 I'll separate into another thread to avoid confusion.

Comment: one more thing, @Paddy, you're just wrong about one point ... all memcached bucket register files into a directory in /data/path - It's clear that is not a object stored for memcached - this is my problem! ...a example below where there are 412 files in path of my bucket ... it is clear to all of us the working process of the buccane type memcached.
`$ /data/couchbase/tokens # memcached bucket call (tokens)
$ ls -la | wc -l
412 # total files`